# Value' does not exist in type 'Overrides & { from?: `0x${string}`

Tags: typescript, wagmi

I have next app with typescript template and using wagmi (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wagmi) package I am trying to send ether to the contract function

Code

```js
const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: "0x53f2d86edcb67c9ea04eada4c2333aebeab717ef",
    abi: [
      {
        name: "mint",
        type: "function",
        stateMutability: "payable",
        inputs: [{ name: "quantity", type: "uint256" }],
        outputs: [],
      },
    ],
    functionName: "mint",
    args: [ethers.BigNumber.from(props.q)],
    overrides: {
      from: "0xfc2df69DF76Fe18866bFc5396f35255e7EFa274a",
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001"),
    },
  });
```

I am getting below error

```
Type '{ from: "0xfc2df69DF76Fe18866bFc5396f35255e7EFa274a"; value: ethers.BigNumber; }' is not assignable to type 'Overrides & { from?: `0x${string}` | undefined; }'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'value' does not exist in type 'Overrides & { from?: `0x${string}` | undefined; }'
```

According to docs (https://wagmi.sh/react/prepare-hooks/usePrepareContractWrite#overrides-optional), I should be able to send ether to the function but I am getting type error

Comment: I wasn't able to fix the types issue so I just disabled types for that particular file by adding `// @ts-nocheck` at the top. This was the only workaround I could find for the issue

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

for type '`0x${string}`  you can use `type Address`

you can import it like this:

`import { Address } from "wagmi";`